# How do I mark a LogDNA or SysDig instance as the default destination for Platform Logs or Metrics?

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm

I'm using the Terraform provider for IBM Cloud to create a LogDNA instance. I'd like to mark this instance as the destination for Platform Logs.

Here is my Terraform:

```
resource ibm_resource_instance logdna_us_south {
  name = "logging-us-south"
  location = "us-south"

  service           = "logdna"
  plan              = "7-day"

  resource_group_id = ibm_resource_group.dev.id
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `default_receiver` parameter when creating the instance as described in https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Log-Analysis-with-LogDNA?topic=Log-Analysis-with-LogDNA-config_svc_logs#platform_logs_enabling_cli

Your terraform should look like:

```
resource ibm_resource_instance logdna_us_south {
  name = "logging-us-south"
  location = "us-south"

  service           = "logdna"
  plan              = "7-day"

  resource_group_id = ibm_resource_group.dev.id

  parameters = {
    "default_receiver" = true
  }
}
```